# GLSL: gl_ModelViewMatrixTranspose vs. gl_ModelViewMatrix

Tags: glsl, matrix

What is the difference between doing these two operations?
Don't the first transform the vector from model space to view space? Then what does the second operation do?

gl_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(vector, 0.0)

gl_ModelViewMatrixTranspose * vec4(vector, 0.0)

Comment: Transposition makes column-major matrix row-major and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose of a matrix is the same as inverting the matrix, as long as the matrix is orthogonal.

So if your gl_ModelView matrix transforms from model space to view space, then the transpose (inverse) of that matrix will transform from view space to model space.

Comment: Thanks, but why sometimes use that instead of gl_ModelViewMatrixInverse?

Comment: added further explanation to answer.

Comment: You're wrong, transpose = inverse only in case of rotation and reflection matrices.

Comment: Invariant - using transpose is much cheaper than inverse, so in cases where it makes sense (such as when you have an orthogonal matrix) using transpose saves a bit of time

Comment: Ocelot - Yes, thank you for pointing that out . I qualified my statement in the edit. Matrix must be orthogonal.

Comment: How are you supposed to transform from model space to view space with an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: I assume what you are asking is..what happens with the translation component? It is there, but usually when I compute my view to model space matrix I pull the translation out, and then transpose. I am guaranteed that what is left is orthogonal. Then I negate my translation and multiply it back in. Still faster than inversion.